# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in... Magento Problem

Tags: magento

I'm trying to setup ZetaPrint on a website. On one of the last steps, I have to do ZetaPrints templates synchronization profile, on System > Import/Export > Advanced Profiles

But When I do the "Add new profile" I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /nfs/c06/h02/mnt/93577/domains/cannafresh.com/html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php on line 117
```

The file is the original one from magento, I can't figure out the error... can anyone help me? Here's the whole code below:

```
<?php

/**
 * Convert Advanced admin controller
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team 
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _initProfile($idFieldName = 'id')
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('System'))
             ->_title($this->__('Import and Export'))
             ->_title($this->__('Profiles'));

        $profileId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam($idFieldName);
        $profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');

        if ($profileId) {
            $profile->load($profileId);
            if (!$profile->getId()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('The profile you are trying to save no longer exists');
                $this->_redirect('*/*');
                return false;
            }
        }

        Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Profiles list action
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('System'))
             ->_title($this->__('Import and Export'))
             ->_title($this->__('Advanced Profiles'));

        if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
            $this->_forward('grid');
            return;
        }
        $this->loadLayout();

        /**
         * Set active menu item
         */
        $this->_setActiveMenu('system/convert');

        /**
         * Append profiles block to content
         */
        $this->_addContent(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/system_convert_profile', 'convert_profile')
        );

        /**
         * Add breadcrumb item
         */
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Import/Export'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Import/Export Advanced'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Advanced Profiles'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Advanced Profiles'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/system_convert_profile_grid')->toHtml());
    }

    /**
     * Profile edit action
     */
     public function editAction()
    {
        $this->_initProfile();
        $this->loadLayout();

        $profile = Mage::registry('current_convert_profile');

        // set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getConvertProfileData(true);

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $profile->addData($data);
        }

        $this->_title($profile->getId() ? $profile->getName() : $this->__('New Profile'));

        $this->_setActiveMenu('system/convert');

        $this->_addContent(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/system_convert_profile_edit')
        );

        /**
         * Append edit tabs to left block
         */
        $this->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/system_convert_profile_edit_tabs'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    }



    /**
     * Create new profile action
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    /**
     * Delete profile action
     */
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $this->_initProfile();
        $profile = Mage::registry('current_convert_profile');
        if ($profile->getId()) {
            try {
                $profile->delete();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('The profile has been deleted.'));
            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }

    /**
     * Save profile action
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            if (!$this->_initProfile('profile_id')) {
                return ;
            }
            $profile = Mage::registry('current_convert_profile');

            // Prepare profile saving data
            if (isset($data)) {
                $profile->addData($data);
            }

            try {
                $profile->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('The profile has been saved.'));
            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setConvertProfileData($data);
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$profile->getId())));
                return;
            }
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('continue')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$profile->getId()));
            } else {
                $this->_redirect('*/*');
            }
        }
        else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Invalid POST data (please check post_max_size and upload_max_filesize settings in your php.ini file).'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*');
        }
    }

    public function runAction()
    {
        $this->_initProfile();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function batchRunAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $batchId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('batch_id',0);
            $rowIds  = $this->getRequest()->getPost('rows');

            $batchModel = Mage::getModel('dataflow/batch')->load($batchId);
            /* @var $batchModel Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch */

            if (!$batchModel->getId()) {
                //exit
                return ;
            }
            if (!is_array($rowIds) || count($rowIds) < 1) {
                //exit
                return ;
            }
            if (!$batchModel->getAdapter()) {
                //exit
                return ;
            }

            $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
            $importIds = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();

            $adapter = Mage::getModel($batchModel->getAdapter());
            $adapter->setBatchParams($batchModel->getParams());

            $errors = array();
            $saved  = 0;

            foreach ($rowIds as $importId) {
                $batchImportModel->load($importId);
                if (!$batchImportModel->getId()) {
                    $errors[] = Mage::helper('dataflow')->__('Skip undefined row.');
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();
                    $adapter->saveRow($importData);
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
                    continue;
                }
                $saved ++;
            }

            $result = array(
                'savedRows' => $saved,
                'errors'    => $errors
            );
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }

    public function batchFinishAction()
    {
        if ($batchId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            $batchModel = Mage::getModel('dataflow/batch')->load($batchId);
            /* @var $batchModel Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch */

            if ($batchModel->getId()) {
                $result = array();
                try {
                    $batchModel->beforeFinish();
                }
                catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result['error'] = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('An error occurred while finishing process. Please refresh the cache');
                }
                $batchModel->delete();
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Customer orders grid
     *
     */
    public function historyAction() {
        $this->_initProfile();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/system_convert_profile_edit_tab_history')->toHtml());
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
//        switch ($this->getRequest()->getActionName()) {
//            case 'index':
//                $aclResource = 'admin/system/convert/profiles';
//                break;
//            case 'grid':
//                $aclResource = 'admin/system/convert/profiles';
//                break;
//            case 'run':
//                $aclResource = 'admin/system/convert/profiles/run';
//                break;
//            default:
//                $aclResource = 'admin/system/convert/profiles/edit';
//                break;
//        }

        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/system/convert/profiles');
    }
}
```

Thanks Luis

Comment: Make my life easier.  What's the exact line with the error on?